# IE/Edge link around SVG with text moves the text

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge

I have the following HTML:

```
<a href="/">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48"/>
        <text y=72>
            <tspan x=50 text-anchor="middle">Hello World</tspan>
        </text>
    </svg>
</a>
```

When I hover over the SVG, the text is shifted right. I check to see if any CSS is added, possibly some padding but nothing is added at all. When I remove the hover, the text stays shifted.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Just tried with Edge, no moving text for me, work as expected

Comment: Yes, I have same problem. And I have not found a solution yet

Comment: Example: http://jsbin.com/cihunadaji/1/edit?html,output  click on the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My poor solution (I haven't found another):

```css
a:hover text, 
a:active text {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```